# Highlight differences between two files, similar to what watch -d produces

Tags: diff, watch

The command `watch -d` produces a very interesting diff: it shows the most recent iteration of the command, and highlights (with inverse video) the differences to the previous iteration. This works specially well when lines are added or modified (deleted/moved lines cause spurious diffs to appear). I would like to use this kind of format to show fileB, with differences to fileA highlighted. This kind of comparisson does not seem to be available with the diff command.

Is it possible to reuse the implementation that watch uses, but not for running commands, but for generic files? I would like to do:

```
watch-diff fileA fileB
```

So that I would see fileB, with changes (as compared to fileA) highlighted.

Comment: `watch diff file1 file2` is not ok for you ?

Comment: Not really. I want the diff to be performed with the exact  same algorithm that watch uses, and shown in the same way (with differences highlighted in reverse video). I have taken a look at the implementation in watch and seems to be very small and specific (not a library, as I initially thought). It is just a loop over all characters in the array, and straight 1 to 1 comparison of characters. Quite easy to implement in any language, but I would like to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: `vimdiff` is also very useful in case you didn't know about it.

Comment: @don_crissti: sure, because probably your fileB is very different from fileA. Now, just change one character (with an editor, for example) and see what happens. Very useful when showing stuff which is properly tabulated and changes just a bit (for example, iptables reports)

Comment: @jeckyll2hide - allright, I see what you mean... I guess you could always write a script that does `cat /path/to/fileA`, watch the script and edit-in-place the path, e.g. `{ sleep 1; sed -i 's/fileA/fileB/' /path/to/myscript; } & watch -d myscript`

Comment: @don_crissti: yes, but I do not want to be constrained by `watch`, I just want to use its diff formatting. For example, `watch` will not allow you to scroll if what you want to display is bigger than the screen. Anyway, I have implemented (in python) a watch-like algorithm (very simple: one-to-one char compare), which produces ansi-escaped output, with the differences highlighted in green. This can be redirected to a file for later analysis or piped to `less -R` to see in-place the differences, with full less-power (scrolling, searching, etc)